# Is it possible to simplify this try catch?

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a question:
Is it possible to simplify these try catch?

Is it possible to only have one try catch and do the transformation in one catch? (Like "If ligne1 == null, ligne 1 = "", if pays == null, pays = "" etc...)
Thank you very much :)

```
try {
    ligne1 = lignes.item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
}catch (NullPointerException e){
    ligne1 = "";
}
try{
    ligne2 = lignes.item(1).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
}catch (NullPointerException e){
    ligne2 = "";
}
try{
    ville = address.getElementsByTagName("city").item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
}catch (NullPointerException e){
    ville = "";
}
try {
    pays = address.getElementsByTagName("country").item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
}catch (NullPointerException e){
    pays = "";
}
```

EDIT:
The NullPointerException is thrown by item(0) if getElementsByTagName returns null. A solution could be to test if getElementsByTagName returns Null or not?

Comment: `catch (NullPointerException e) {...}` -- no, **never** do this. Test for null instead and avoid NPE's. Don't do in a try/catch what should be done in an if/else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** do:

```
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    //....
}
```

Don't do in a try/catch what should be done in an if/else. Instead why not simply create a method for this:

```
public String emptyIfNull(String input) {
    return input == null ? "" : input;
}
```

```
ligne1 = emptyIfNull(lignes.item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent());
ligne2 = emptyIfNull(lignes.item(1).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent());
ville = emptyIfNull(address.getElementsByTagName("city").item(0).getAttributes()
        .item(0).getTextContent());
pays = emptyIfNull(address.getElementsByTagName("country").item(0).getAttributes()
        .item(0).getTextContent());
```

Comment: I edited my question, it's item(0) after the getElementsByTagName that throws the exception.

Comment: @Couldosh: simply check for null *before* the exception is thrown